# Get subset of employees based on parameters

Tags: c#, linq

I have done paging with sorting in stored procedures. But now, I need to do the same in LINQ for the following object.  What is the **most readable** LINQ query for achieving sorting and paging in the following scenario?

#### CODE

```
static  List<Employee> GetMyData(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int itemCount, string sortField, string sortDirection )
{

    Employee e1= new Employee(){EmpID = 1, EmpName = "E1"};
    Employee e2= new Employee(){EmpID = 2, EmpName = "E2"};
    Employee e3= new Employee(){EmpID = 3, EmpName = "E3"};
    Employee e4= new Employee(){EmpID = 4, EmpName = "E4"};
    Employee e5= new Employee(){EmpID = 5, EmpName = "E5"};
    Employee e6= new Employee(){EmpID = 6, EmpName = "E6"};

    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
    employees.Add(e1);
    employees.Add(e2);
    employees.Add(e3);
    employees.Add(e4);
    employees.Add(e5);
    employees.Add(e6);

    itemCount = employees.Count;

    //Get subset of employees based on paging and sorting parameters
    //Sorting can be based on EmpID or EmpName
    List<Employee> currentPageEmployees = null;
    return currentPageEmployees;
}
```

Calling the method

```
        int count = 0;
        List<Employee> e = GetMyData(0, 2, out count, "EmpID", "descending");
```

Comment: You can easy sort elements use link, but for paging i think simple 'For' cicle will be easy for understanding, than linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom selector in order to resolve `sortField` to the appropriate property of the Employee type. Then for sort direction I make the assumption that `sortDirection` is either ascending or descending - if it is then maybe a `bool` is better?

Given that here's an example:

```
var selector = new Func<Employee, object>(e => e.GetType().GetProperty(sortField).GetValue(e, null));
var query = sortDirection.Equals("descending", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                ? employees.OrderByDescending(selector)
                : employees.OrderBy(selector);

List<Employee> currentPageEmployees = query
    .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

There is Dynamic Linq extensions that might make things more readble.

Edit: removed casting

Comment: I don't think the `GetValue(e, null)` is able to be casted as `Employee`, it is `int` if the `sortField = "EmpID"` and it is `string` if the `sortField = "EmpName"`. So I think you should convert it to `int` or `string`, not `Employee`.

Comment: The following should return "E6" but returning "E2". `List<Employee> e = GetMyData(1, 1, out count, "EmpID", "descending");`

Comment: @KingKing you're probably right, wrote the code off the cuff - i.e. not tested

Comment: @Lijo I've updated the selector to remove the casting. Should be returning in descending order now. Be aware that pageIndex should be 0 if you want to see record 6 for the given code above.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting by any field can be done only AFAIK using Dynamic linq http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Sorting:

```
if (sortDirection == "ASC") 
    employees = employees.OrderBy(sortField).ToList();
else 
   employees = employees.OrderByDesceding(sortField).ToList();
```

Paging:

```
var currentPageEmployees = sorted.Skip(pageindex*pageSize).Take(pageSize)
```

EDIT: updated code with sortField and sortDirection

Comment: What about `sortField` and `sortDirection`, it's not such simple, you have to change the query accordingly to the parameters `sortField` and `sortDirection`.

Answer (score 1):

For `sorting` you can use `orderby` method of linq specifying the parameter on which you want to apply sorting.

```
 var result = employess.OrderBy(x=>x.Name);
 ar result = employess.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Name);
```

for `paging` you can use `SKip` and `Take` methods in collaboration like this

```
 var queryResultPage = employess
                      .Skip(numberOfObjectsPerPage * pageNumber)
                      .Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<Employee> currentPageEmployees = employees.OrderBy(p => ((sortField == "EmpID") ? p.EmpID : (((sortField == "EmpName") ? p.EmpName : (p.EmpID))))).Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

**[refrence](http://afana.me/post/paging-sorting-and-searching-ef-cf-and-mvc.aspx)**

Comment: Should notice the OP that `pageIndex` is 1-based not zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

Others use `Skip` and `Take`, which is OK however we can also use `Where`:

```
enum SortDirection {
    Ascending,
    Descending
}

static  List<Employee> GetMyData(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int itemCount, string sortField, SortDirection sortDirection )
{

    //.........
    //.........  

    int startIndex = pageIndex * pageSize; //pageIndex is Zero-based
    int endIndex = startIndex + pageSize;

    //Get subset of employees based on paging and sorting parameters
    //Sorting can be based on EmpID or EmpName <-- this is why I can use the ? below
    List<Employee> currentPageEmployees = 
          sortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? 
          employees.OrderBy(e=>sortField=="EmpID" ? e.EmpID : e.EmpName)
                   .Where((e,i)=>i>=startIndex&&i<endIndex)
          :
          employees.OrderByDescending(e=>sortField=="EmpID" ? e.EmpID : e.EmpName)
                   .Where((e,i)=>i>=startIndex&&i<endIndex);
    return currentPageEmployees;
}
```